# Rails4 - How to dynamically set the background image of a div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my webapp, every user can add his own image.
I display the users's image using the following code.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:preview) , :class => "imagescale" %>
</div>
```

I want the user's image to be the background of a div with class testcover which is as follows right now. It displays a static image but I want to dynamically change it to user's image.

```
<div class="testcover">
<p>hello<p>
</div>

.testcover
background: #2c3e50 image-url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/zzzz.jpg") no-repeat
```

How do I make the user's image as the background of the div? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="testcover" style="background: url(<%= @user.avatar.url(:preview) %>) no-repeat">
    <p>hello<p>
</div>
```

Something like that should work. So you have to define the background CSS property inline, within the div tag itself, and just set it to the URL of your image.